# How to make work IntelliSense always (always show members list) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

when I type a new code (new word), a list of members is displayed instant and fine. But when I click(switch) to already exist word and for exapmle press backspace - the member list not displayed, and I need to predd CTRL+J to call Members list.
For example in "Visual Studio Code" and "Xcode" as soon as you press backspace, the Members List is displayed.
Maybe Visual Studio (2015\17\19) has some kind of option?

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi, I found the extenson "Visual Assist" - it's work as I need [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WholeTomatoSoftware.VisualAssist)

Comment: It seems this issue is resolved now, you could consider adding self answer and mark it to share the useful info. See [can i answer my own...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) Just a reminder:)

Answer (score 2):

As I know the behavior of `Intellisense` varies in different programming languages(Project types).

1.For those C#, VB.net projects, in VS you can go `Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>C#/Basic=>Intellisense=>To control the behavior`, see:

[image]

The `Show completion list after a character is deleted` option is something you want. Enable it and then if you press backspace, the member list will display.

2.However it seems you're in C++ projects(checking your SO tags), for C++ projects, you can find Intellisense-related settings at `Tools=>Options=>Text Editor=>C/C++=>Advanced`:

[image]

There's no option which supports this behavior.(backspace or delete something and show member list). So if you're in C++ projects, I'm afraid the answer is negative, for now you do need to press `CTRL+J` to call Members list. And if you do need that option in C++ projects, I recommend that you post an suggestion for your requirement in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) by `suggest a feature` button to let the team know.

Hope all above helps resolve your issue.

Comment: Is anyone aware if this has changed for C++? Looked around the Developer Community but searcher is trash and returns 170k results with totally unrelated issues to my search.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me. Just disable predictive IntelliSense
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT0g6.png

Comment: Answer is not self contained. Please don’t depend on external links.